# Are all derivations of a matrix algebra inner derivations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a *subalgebra* of $M_n(\mathbb{R}).$ Let $$d:\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$$ be a linear map satisfying the Leibnitz rule $$d(XY)=d(X)\cdot Y-X\cdot d(Y)$$ for all $X,Y \in \mathcal{A}$

Is it true that $$d(X)=AX-XA$$ for some $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})?$

**In case $\mathcal{A}=M_n(\mathbb{R})$ the statement is well known to be true.**

Comment: I guess you mean to require $X,Y\in \mathcal{A}$ rather than $X,Y\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$?  And do you mean to require $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ or $A\in\mathcal{A}$ at the end?

Comment: The Leibniz rule is with a plus sign, not a minus sign

Comment: Say $n=2m$ even, $A$ the set of matrices of the form $tI_{2m}+\begin{pmatrix}0 & X\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Each linear endomorphism of this algebra of the form $tI_{2m}+\begin{pmatrix}0 & X\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0 & f(X)\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $f$ linear endomorphism, is a derivation. The space of such derivations has dimension $m^4=n^4/16$. This is $> n^2-1$ (dim of the set of inner derivation) as soon as $n\ge 4$. Of course there should be easy explicit examples.